# MongoDB update not below zero

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a real time feature for my app which contains a set of items. Each user can get a certain amount of items but I'm wondering how I should handle this:

```
Items left: 7
User A wants 5 items
User B wants 5 items
```

And they both pressed the button on the exact same time.
Because of the write/lock thing if I do this will only one person gets it? Or will they both get it and my items count will be -3 or?

```
var number = 5
    .update(
        {$where : "items > number -1"},
        {$inc: {"items": -number}},
        {multi: true}
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MongoDB manual:

> MongoDB allows multiple clients to read and write the same data. In order to ensure consistency, it uses locking and other concurrency
>   control measures to prevent multiple clients from modifying the same
>   piece of data simultaneously. Together, these mechanisms guarantee
>   that all writes to a single document occur either in full or not at
>   all and that clients never see an inconsistent view of the data.

So MongoDB takes care of it.